# Is it possible to increase pod limit in WSL2

Tags: kubernetes, wsl-2

Is it possible to increase pod limit in WSL2 . (default max is 110)
I want to run 140 pods.

Answer (score 0):

`--max-pods int32` is [kubelet parameter](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/), hence you can play with it if you have an access to required node

> --max-pods int32 Number of Pods that can run on this Kubelet. (default 110) (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file
> specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/
> for more information.)

Check [How to increase the number of pods limit per Kubernetes Node](https://medium.com/@initcron/how-to-increase-the-number-of-pods-limit-per-kubernetes-node-877dcec5e4fa), that may help.

You should locate kubelet config file, add to the bottom `--max-pods=140` and restart kubelet service.

In case of `kubeadm`, this is `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`. Restart: `systemctl restart kubelet`

In case of `microk8s`, that usually goes on top of wsl2, this is `/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kubelet`. Restart: `service snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet restart`. [The Kubernetes 110 pod limit per node](https://blog.kubovy.eu/2020/05/16/the-kubernetes-110-pod-limit-per-node/)